# Distribution of t-statistic with two small sample sizes

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence, sampling

Let

- $X_1,...,X_n\stackrel{i.i.d}\sim N(μ_0,σ_0^2)$
- $Y_1,...,Y_m\stackrel{i.i.d}\sim N(μ_1,σ_1^2)$
- the $X_i$'s are independent of the $Y_i$'s

where $μ_0,μ_1,σ_0^2,σ_1^2$ are unknown parameters.

Suppose the data collected are summarized as follows:

- Sample sizes: $n=m=5$;
- Sample means:

  - $\bar{X}_{n}=1.2$
  - $\bar{Y}_{m}=1.0$
- Sample variances: $\hat{\sigma}_1^2=\hat{\sigma}_2^2=0.5$.

Choosing from the following distributions that **best approximates** the distribution of the $t$-statistic $T_{n=5,m=5}$ under the null hypothesis $H_0 ∶μ_0=μ_1$:

- Normal distribution with mean $μ≠0$
- Standard normal distribution
- $t$-distribution
- $F$-distribution

The most "plausible" distribution would be the $t$-distribution. Seems about right?

My question is related to the degrees of freedom (assuming my choice of distribution is correct).

For the $t$-distribution, the $t$-statistic is given by

$$ T_n =\frac{\bar{X_{n}}-\bar{Y_{m}}}{\sqrt{\hat{\sigma}_1^2/m+\hat{\sigma}_0^2/n}}$$

The general formula is $df = n_1 + n_2 - 2$, where $n_1,n_2$ are $n,m$ respectively so $T_n \sim t_{n+m-2, \alpha/2}$ therefore $df=8$. On the other hand, according to Welch-Satterthwaite's (WS) formula (which calculates an approximation to the effective degrees of freedom), under $H_0$, $T_n$ is approximately distributed as $t_{40}$ where $df=40$.

Which $df$ value is the correct one?

The problem says "**best approximates**" so WS makes sense but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Welch’s $t$-test is used when the population variances are assumed unequal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welch’s $t$-test is used when the population variances are assumed unequal.

You may conduct a test such as F-test, Levene’s test, Bartlett’s test, to assess the equality of variance assumption.

This may lead to inflated Type I error though, so it may be wise to specify *a priori* which test to use.

If the sample sizes are equal, student’s $t$-test is robust to unequal variances. (Welch’s $t$-test is robust regardless.)

Comment: Thank you for the insight @Jellyfish . I'm not given population variances, only sample variances. If I understand correctly, since both the sample sizes and sample variances are equal, I should stick with WS $df=40$ due to robustness?

Comment: @nimen55290 it sounds like a reasonable decision, but for the reason you gave it should be original $t$-test

Comment: Sorry, I'm little lost @Jellyfish . You said "the reason you gave it should be original $$-test". What reason? The fact that the samples (except mean) are equal or that it should be the **best approximation**?

Comment: @nimen55290 since you said the sample variances are equal, this would imply the pop variances might be equal w/o conducting a F test, say. this would suggest an original $t$-test. you also said the sample sizes are equal, which makes $t$-test robust to unequal variance

Comment: So why say $df=40$ is a "reasonable decision"? This just confuses me, so do you refer to "original" t-test where $df=8$ or did I misinterpret that? @Jellyfish

Comment: @nimen55290 i meant it sounds a reasonable decision if you replace Welch t-test $df=40$ in your first comment with original t-test $df=8$